# Bootstrap table not allow clicks (link) on search or filter result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap table and use [this example](https://codepen.io/AurelieT/pen/JGxMgo) and added click function which working fine until I apply any bootstrap features such as filtering, search, pagination, and others after applying any bootstrap features not able to click as before my table-row function not work, and not able to get table row id for selected checkbox its only show (`'btSelectItem': ['on', 'on']`) on Django View console instead of table id or name once click some button.

```html
<td class='table-row' data-href="{% url 'detail' item.slug%}">
  {{ item.item_name }}
</td>
```

**my css style**

```css
.table-row {cursor:pointer;color: blue; }
```

**query for click**

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".table-row").click(function() {
    window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
  });
});
```

**This is how my code look like :-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Bootstrap Table - Filter control</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>

<style>
.table-row{
cursor:pointer;
color: blue;
}
.container {
    width: 1024px;
    padding: 2em;
}

.bold-blue {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0277BD;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="#">
  <button class="button button2"type="submit", name="Delete", value="Delete">Delete</button>
  <button class="button button2" type="submit", name="save", value="save">Save</button>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">


<div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">Export Basic</option>
                <option value="all">Export All</option>
                <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
        </select>
</div>

<table id="table" 
            data-toggle="table"
            data-search="true"
            data-show-refresh="true"
            data-show-columns="true"
            data-filter-control="true"
            data-show-export="true"
            data-show-pagination-switch="true"
            data-pagination="true"
            data-page-list="[5, 25, 50, 100, all]"
            data-page-size="5"
            data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
            <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
            <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Examen</th>
            <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class='table-row' data-href="https://google.com">Valérie</td>
            <td>01/09/2015</td>
            <td>Français</td>
            <td>12/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="1" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td class='table-row' data-href="https://google122.com">Eric</td>
            <td>05/09/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>8/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="2" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>05/09/2015</td>
            <td class='table-row' data-href="https://ask.com">mydata</td>
            <td>4/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="3" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>05/09/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>10/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="4" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>01/09/2015</td>
            <td>Français</td>
            <td>14/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="5" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>07/09/2015</td>
            <td>Mathématiques</td>
            <td>19/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="6" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>01/09/2015</td>
            <td>Français</td>
            <td>11/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="7" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>01/10/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>8/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="8" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>07/09/2015</td>
            <td>Mathématiques</td>
            <td>14/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="9" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valérie</td>
            <td>01/10/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>12/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="10" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>07/09/2015</td>
            <td>Mathématiques</td>
            <td>14/20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="11" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Valentin</td>
            <td>01/10/2015</td>
            <td>Philosophie</td>
            <td>10/20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".table-row").click(function() {
          window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
      });
  });
</script>

<script>
var $table = $('#table');
    $(function () {
        $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                exportDataType: $(this).val()
            });
        });
    })

        var trBoldBlue = $("table");

    $(trBoldBlue).on("click", "tr", function (){
            $(this).toggleClass("bold-blue");
    });
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does console.log return? Can you show your html where you plug in scripts?

Comment: console.log(table); just return my Html complete file with row and columns, which console.log i need to look ?

Comment: If you look above code click function work and redirect to url as expected but when i apply any filter, search or any Bootstrap table features it stops working. click should work even with filter & search. I even tried to remove all functions and keep only .table-row but even it same.

Comment: Anyone has any advice ?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for being blind.
Try this:

```js
            $("body").on("click", ".table-row", function () {
                window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
            });
```

Comment: NO it's still the same, after apply filter herf not working :(

Comment: Awesome It worked Thank you. do you have any idea why my Delete & Save button not giving table row id or name ?   its only shows 'btSelectItem': ['on', 'on'] "on" based on row selected.

Comment: Do you try smth like this? https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#methods/remove.html#view-source

Comment: Any idea how to control the checkbox with Django function my django **view.py**   
 `request.POST.get("save"):
        print(request.POST.get)
        for item in items.all():
            if request.POST.get("c" + str(item.id)) == "clicked":
                print(item.id)`  
my html table check box header `<th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>` and table body checkbox `<td class="bs-checkbox "><input type="checkbox", value="clicked", name="c{{host.id}}"</td> `

Comment: Even when i export to CSV by using bootstrap table export, the checkbox column replaced by **on** it should not show that checkbox column as **on**. Not sure how to get item id instead of 'on'.

Comment: Any Idea how to deal Bootstrap checkbox with Django?

Comment: Any Idea how to achieve bootstrap table  check box with Django